# CETAS TSQL query is not generating csv files with headers

Tags: t-sql, azure-synapse

I am writing a CETAS(create external table as select) query in TSQL using synapse. As all these CETAS queries generate a .csv file in a location (in storage account/data lake gen2), none of these files have headers.

Is there a possible solution or work-around using tsql or synapse analytics?

The following query is from azure documentation, this is also missing headers

```
-- use CETAS to export select statement with OPENROWSET result to  storage
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE population_by_year_state
WITH (
    LOCATION = 'aggregated_data/',
    DATA_SOURCE = population_ds,  
    FILE_FORMAT = census_file_format
)  
AS
SELECT decennialTime, stateName, SUM(population) AS population
FROM
    OPENROWSET(BULK 'https://azureopendatastorage.blob.core.windows.net/censusdatacontainer/release/us_popula 
 tion_county/year=*/*.parquet',
    FORMAT='PARQUET') AS [r]
GROUP BY decennialTime, stateName
GO

-- you can query the newly created external table
SELECT * FROM population_by_year_state
```

In my case I have a JSON and other also result set of previously created external tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is your file format defined? Here is the code we use that generates column headers:

```
DROP EXTERNAL FILE FORMAT EXT_File_Format_CSV

CREATE EXTERNAL FILE FORMAT EXT_File_Format_CSV
WITH (  
    FORMAT_TYPE = DELIMITEDTEXT,
    FORMAT_OPTIONS (
        FIELD_TERMINATOR = ',',
        STRING_DELIMITER = '"',
        PARSER_VERSION = '2.0',
        FIRST_ROW = 2
    )
);
```

Comment: Any reason for using Parser version 2? Will it be ok if we use parser version 1?

Comment: I've been using Synapse since private preview, and I have never once used parser version 1.